# Pagination click event not working on page numbers in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using the jquery datatables . I want to perform some functions on click of pagination numbers of the table . The rows of the table are getting generated dynamically. The issue is that the **onclick** event is not getting fired when clicking on numbers but it is getting fired on the previous and next links.

I have used the following to bind the click function :

```
 $(document).on('click',"div.pagination li",function(evt){
 evt.preventDefault();
 alert('clicked!');
 // do some coding
  });
```

Kindly help me in identifying what is the mistake here. Kindly suggest if there is an alternative method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pagination links are created through JQuery then .click may not work instead use .bind